Código Python que copie archivos de una carpeta hacia la carpeta superior
Buen día, me podrían ayudar guiándome para realizar un código en Python que haga lo siguiente:
Tengo una carpeta en D: que se llama Servidor, dentro de esta tengo otra que se llama Reportes. Dentro de la de reportes tengo varias que tienen un ID que corresponde a alguien y dentro de ese ID tengo los reportes por fecha, por ejemplo:
D:/Servidor/Reportes/123456789/2022-08-24/archivo.rtf

Hay ocasiones, que por error de software (ya reportado, pero no me lo corrigen), crea otra carpeta extra con el nombre del reporte y dentro de ella guarda el archivo .rtf, por lo que tengo que hacer la busqueda manual y extraerla. Ejemplo:
D:/Servidor/Reportes/CarpetaID/2022-08-24/REPORTE/archivo.rtf

o genenerico asi:
D:/CARPETA1/CARPETA2/CARPETA3/CARPETA4/CARPETA5/Archivo.rtf

Allí tengo que copiar el archivo.rtf que esta en la carpeta REPORTE (carpeta5) y pegarlo en la carpeta 2022-08-24 (carpeta4) para que el sistema lo pueda leer.
¿Habría la manera de hacer esto automatizado? o sea, ver como entrar hasta la carpeta 5 y copiar el archivo a la carpeta 4. ¿O de plano ya no le busco y me doy por vencido hasta que me corrijan el software?
Tengo algunos años que no programo, me parece interesante Python, me estoy adentrando un poco para crear soluciones a problemas que desarollo no me ha resuelto.
Actualizacion:
Al final quedo esto y hace exactamente lo que necesitaba gracias.
Este fue el resultado final, lo converti en .exe y ya esta en el servidor, muchas gracias:
ruta='D:/SERVIDOR/REPORTES/*/*/*'   
from operator import contains
import os, glob, shutil

from tkinter import END
    for repfolder in glob.glob(ruta):
       if  ".rtf" not in repfolder and ".html" not in repfolder: #verifica que no sean archivos, sino carpetas
    for elem in os.listdir(repfolder): 
      src = os.path.join(repfolder, elem) #ubicacion
      dst = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(repfolder), elem)#destino
      shutil.move(src, dst) # Mueve los archivos
      #shutil.rmtree(repfolder, ignore_errors=True) # Elimina los directorio */REPORTE
END


Con bat no sé, pero con algo como javascript o python eso es un suspiro

En teoría, es posible. Solo necesitas una tarea programada que se ejecute periódicamente buscando nuevos reportes. Si encuentra alguno, valida que el path tenga el formato correcto (con expresión regular). Si cumple con la expresion regular, calcula el path al que debe moverse y lo mueve. El lenguaje es irrelevante mientras el servidor lo soporte. Con BAT, el servidor lo ejecuta directamente, pero con Python, JS o Groovy, necesitas installar un intérprete. La ventaja de estos últimos es que son más sencillos de usar.

Tampoco conozco mucho de bat, pero adicional a lo que ya han comentado, en PHP también sería muy sencillo y "no hay que instalar nada"; solo que el equipo tenga el Visual C++ Redistributable (vcredist) mínimo correspondiente. Pero bueno, si te interesa ese camino, y si le pudieras instalar Python o NodeJs al servidor, o si ya tiene vcredist 2015-2022 x64 instalado (para la opción PHP), puedes editar la pregunta e indicar un lenguaje de esos.

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo. Mi propuesta contempla, además del movimiento de los archivos, la eliminación de los directorios REPORTE.
El método glob.glob localizará todos los directorios que cumplan con pattern. Se recorre cada una de esas rutas con el primer for. En el for más interno serán recorridos 1 a 1 los archivos que contenga la ruta actual y, si los hay, son movidos al directorio padre.
El directorio REPORTE actual será eliminado al finalizar cada ciclo del primer for.
import os, glob, shutil

pattern = 'D:/Servidor/Reportes/*/*/REPORTE'
for repfolder in glob.glob(pattern):
    for elem in os.listdir(repfolder):
        src = os.path.join(repfolder, elem)
        dst = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(repfolder), elem)
        shutil.move(src, dst) # Mueve los archivos
    shutil.rmtree(repfolder, ignore_errors=True) # Elimina los directorio */REPORTE

[!] La línea shutil.rmtree(repfolder) elimina los directorios REPORTE con todo su contenido, aunque se supone que en ese momento ya deben estar vacíos. Si te da algo de temor, la primera vez comenta esa línea, ejecutas el script y si todo salió correcto, la descomentas y vuelves a ejecutar.

Muchas gracias por su apoyo, logre realizar la tarea agregando algunos detalles a la sugerencia de aeportugal.
